# WildFly 10.1 starts on different IP but still tries to connect to 127.0.0.1:9990 for HTTP remoting and failing to connect

Tags: wildfly, jbpm, wildfly-10

I am using jBPM 7.3. Everything works fine while starting but after around 5 minutes it tries to connect to `127.0.0.1:9990` port. Yet I have specified my IP address while starting as `./standalone.sh -b 10.14.24.161`.

Even I changed it in `standalone.xml` but it is still trying to connect with localhost IP. The error I am getting is the following:

```
2017-09-18 19:45:44,195 ERROR [org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.backend.integration.wildfly.WildflyBaseClient] (pool-22-thread-1) It was not possible to open connection to Wildfly/EAP server.: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:80)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.backend.integration.wildfly.WildflyBaseClient.testConnection(WildflyBaseClient.java:158)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.backend.integration.wildfly.WildflyBaseClient.testConnection(WildflyBaseClient.java:147)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.backend.core.wildfly.WildflyDriverProvider.hasStarted(WildflyDriverProvider.java:210)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.backend.core.wildfly.WildflyDriverProvider$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.hasStarted(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.backend.core.impl.DataSourceRuntimeManagerImpl.hasStarted(DataSourceRuntimeManagerImpl.java:199)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.backend.core.impl.DataSourceRuntimeManagerImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.hasStarted(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.backend.DataSourceManagementBootstrap.lambda$getInitializeDeploymentsTask$0(DataSourceManagementBootstrap.java:172)
    at org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.backend.DataSourceManagementBootstrap$$Lambda$241/1920820624.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:122)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:257)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:71)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.FutureManagementChannel$Establishing.getChannel(FutureManagementChannel.java:218)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:147)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:122)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:263)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:168)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:147)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread$ConnectHandle.handleReady(WorkerThread.java:321)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:567)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:276)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:393)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:381)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connect(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:114)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same error @Rupesh. No idea on how to solve it until now.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the following parameters in the datasource-management.properties file located in the /WEB-INF/classes/ directory of your KieWorkbench distribution file.
e.g. in kie-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war

```
datasource.management.wildfly.host=<your_hostname_or_ip>
datasource.management.wildfly.port=<your_port>
datasource.management.wildfly.admin=<your_admin_user>
datasource.management.wildfly.password=<your_admin_password>
datasource.management.wildfly.realm=ApplicationRealm
```

Thanks to Walter Medvedeo, who came up with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have added following argument in start script(build.xml). And it seems to solved the error.

```
<arg value="-Dorg.uberfire.ext.security.management.wildfly.cli.port=<changed_port>"/>
```

my port was offsetted by 150 so I used 10140